# Как скачать проект с Unity Cloud?

Tags: unity-hub

Я знаю, что есть точно такой вопрос в StackOverflow на английском. Но она не решает мои проблемы. А также и на "Add Remote project", и во вкладке "Projects" нету ни одного проекта. Возможно проблема в том, что я вообще их в Unity Cloud не ложил. Но если начать все с начала, то вот:

Перед тем, как создать проект, я выбрал **организацию**, а также включил галочку на "Connect to Unity Cloud". После этого создал проект и работал над ним. Вскоре я их удалил из-за нехватки места на диске, но через месяц я снова хотел работать над ними, но я не знал как их скачать. Сперва проверил Unity Cloud. Там были показаны все мои проекты, но скачать я их оттуда не могу.

[image: Мои проекты в Unity Cloud]